# Can I pass a non-generic type where a generic type is expected?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to define a set of classes that collect and persist data. I want to call them either on-demand basis, or in a chain-of-responsibility fashion, as the caller pleases.

To support the chaining, I have declared my interface like so:

```
interface IDataManager<T, K>
{
    T GetData(K args);
    void WriteData(Stream stream);
    void WriteData(T data, Stream stream);

    IDataCollectionPolicy Policy;

    IDataManager<T, K> NextDataManager;
}
```

But the T's and K's for each concrete types will be different. If I give it like this:

```
IDataManager<T, K> NextDataManager;
```

I assume that the calling code will only be able to chain types that have the same T's and K's. Is there a way I can have it chain any type of IDataManager?

One thing that occurs to me is to have IDataManager inherit from a non-generic IDataManager like so:

```
interface IDataManager { }

interface IDataManager<T, K>: IDataManager
{
    T GetData(K args);
    void WriteData(Stream stream);
    void WriteData(T data, Stream stream);

    IDataCollectionPolicy Policy;

    IDataManager NextDataManager;
}
```

Is this going to work?

Answer (score 4):

Splitting an interface into a generic and a non-generic part is a common pattern, especially if you move non-generic methods to the non-generic interface:

```
interface IDataManager
{
    void WriteData(Stream stream);
    IDataCollectionPolicy Policy { get; set; }
    IDataManager NextDataManager { get; set; }
}

interface IDataManager<T, K> : IDataManager
{
    T GetData(K args);
    void WriteData(T data, Stream stream);
}
```

Comment: That's what I wondered. Thank you.

With that, then, am I going to be able to say:

SomeClassThatImplementsIDataManager<string, int> obj = new ...
AnotherSuchClass<string, ArrayList> nextOne = new ...

obj.Next = nextOne;

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your proposed solution is correct. The general practice is (as you describe) to create a non-generic base class/interface, then a generic class/interface that implements/inherits from it.